# fieldset hide/show when choose dropdown

Tags: angularjs

I have a form with 5 different products and attributes for it, i want only show a single product field-set(1 product) when user choose from dropdown menu and increment

```
$scope.choices = [{id:'choice1'},{id:'choice1'},];

//New element adding function
$scope.addNewChoice = function(){
    var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
    $scope.choices.push({'id':'choice'+newItemNo})
}

//Remove an evidence item from the form
$scope.removeChoice = function(){
    var lastItem = $scope.choices.length-1;
    $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
}
```

this is how i make dynamic form field but inside a each row there is my fieldset but i want only show particular product fieldset when user choose that product

Comment: show your view code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside HTML formfield set

```
<fieldset ng-if='showField($index,"item")'> 
...........
</fieldset>



$scope.showField = function(index,item){

       if($scope.choices[index]['item'] == item){

           return true;
       }
}
```